# Using Matlab to find output at specified input values

Tags: matlab

```
spacing_Pin  = transpose(-27:0.0001:2); 
thetah_2nd   = Phi_intrp3(ismembertol(spacing_Pin,P_in2nd));
```

With this code, I want to evaluate `Phi_intrp3`at indices where `spacing_Pin`is equal to `P_in2nd`

I know I have asked similar questions before. And I have got some really helpful answers already. But in this case they do not seem to apply. `P_in2nd`has only 40 entries, whereas `spacing_Pin`has far more.  Therefore I cannot consider the absolute value of the difference of `spacing_Pin`and `P_in2nd`to find out where they are closest to equal.

so `P_in2nd`has values between  -25.9747 and -0.0147. The decimals have 4 digits after the dot, but these are sometimes rounded by Matlab (format short). That's the catch, I think, `P_in2nd` is not found in `spacing_Pin`. The result is an empty matrix.

Here's the first 5 entries of `P_in2nd`:

- -25,9747431735299
- -24,9747431735299
- -23,9947431735299
- -23,0047431735299
- -22,0047431735299

Now, I want to evaluate ¸`Phi_intrp3`at these values. For this purpose I can change `spacing_Pin`, but not `P_in2nd`. For example, when I search for the first entry of `P_in2nd`in `spacing_Pin`, I find that entry 10254 = -25,9747000000000. So I want to evaluate `Phi_intrp3`at this input entry. 
Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Are you simply trying to do nearest neighbor interpolation? It's really not clear what you want at all. Please show actual inputs and expected outputs. And the decimals have MORE than four decimal points it's just MATLAB that's displaying that way. Call `format long` to change that

Comment: ok. I hope it is clearer now. Sorry to be confusing